# Problema Uncaught ReferenceError: resposta is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To com um problema, no envio de dados usando ajax, a minha função sempre retorna esse mesmo erro: **Uncaught ReferenceError: resposta is not defined;**

Função que passa os dados::

```
function salvaDadosHistorico(username,valorDado,resultado,nunSorteados){

    dados = 'username='+username+',valorDado='+valorDado+',resultado='+resultado+',nunSorteados='+nunSorteados;


    resp = chamadaAjax(dados,'core/historico-control.php','POST');
    return resp;

}
```

função que ta dando o erro:

```
function chamadaAjax(dados,rota,type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        data: dados,
        url: rota,
        success: function (res)
        {
            resposta = res;
        },
        error: function(res)
        {
            resposta = res;
        } 
    })
    return resposta;
}
```

Comment: Quando chega nesta linha `return resposta;`, a variável `resposta` não existe. O que tá dentro do AJAX é processo depois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que sua requisição *ajax* é uma função assíncrona, então a variável resposta ainda não existe pois o *ajax* ainda está em execução.
Uma possível solução é usar a função $.when() do jquery para aguardar a *promisse*.

```js
function chamadaAjax(dados,rota,type) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: type,
        data: dados,
        url: rota,
    })
}


//ai você pode chamar sua função salvardadoshistoricos passando a função de sucesso e erro ou editar da forma que achar melhor
function salvaDadosHistorico(funcaoSucesso,funcaoErro){

    dados = {}
    chamadaAjax(dados,'https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/','GET').done(funcaoSucesso).fail(funcaoErro);
}

function funcaoSucesso(response) {
console.table(response);
}

function funcaoErro(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

salvaDadosHistorico(funcaoSucesso,funcaoErro);
```

Existem diversas formas, como o uso de await por exemplo. Procure por funções assíncronas.

[Aqui está o link documentação da função do jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Testei esse código e ele me retorna Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: Olá @LukasTakahashi, Efetuei uma alteração do código para uma Url que eu possuia acesso, testei aqui e funcionou normalmente, se puder valide ai novamente. Não se esqueça de importar  o Jquery antes. Grande Abraço.

Comment: Bgd pela ajuda, de inicio eu queria não ter que criar uma nova função pra executar os dados, só retornar a resposta da chamada ajax como callback da função salvaDadosHistorico(). Mais acabei por desistir dessa ideia e sua resposta ajudou muito a resolver esse problema.

Comment: @LukasTakahashi, você pode retornar também, por exemplo fazendo `salvaDadosHistorico(foo,bar) { return chamadaAjax(dados,url); }` Ai você trata a promisse na sua outra função. Na sua função inicial você pode usar funções anônimas também. O importante é sempre tratar esse retorno seja com when ou com await (await só funciona em navegadores mais novos). Ainda existe a opção de um ajax async (mais isto não é recomendado). E ainda existem outras formas rs. Sucesso ai!!